# Viewshed 2 not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst

I am trying to run  model using viewshed 2 and get the following error code:

> Error 00248: the spatial reference is not defined.

Can anyone tell me what this means?

Comment: That's a pretty descriptive error. Doesn't it make sense that Viewshed would need to know how the X/Y and Z extents relate before it could make any calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Your data have an incorrect or missing coordinate system.

You can fix it with [Define Projection](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/define-projection.htm):

> This tool is intended for datasets that have an unknown or incorrect
> coordinate system defined.